# How to get list of all databases from arango console?

Tags: arangodb

I do not see any function in `help` about getting all existing databases in ArangoDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the list of all existing databases from the Arango console (I am referring to the ArangoShell here), you can use:

```
db._databases();
```

In case you are looking for other methods: the shell has auto-completion, so you can type `db.` and then press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. This will show the list of available properties/functions for the given object if it exists (and is a variable).